# Javascript - accessing object value by variable html text

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown button with class '.tVal'. When the user selects an option from the dropdown, the button's text is changed to that option. If I select 'two' from the dropdown, $('.tVal').text() returns 'two'.

I would like to retrieve a value from the object Translate using the selection as the key. But when I try to access Translate with the variable, it returns undefined. I have confirmed that num is a string and returns 'two'.

```
var Translate = {
    one: '1',
    two: '2'
};
var num = $(".tVal").text(); //returns 'two'
Translate[num]; //returns undefined
```

Comment: Does it return *only* 'two'? Are you sure there's no white-space included? Try `console.log('two' === num);`

Comment: That was it! Stripping the white-space fixed it.

Comment: Not sure what dropdown exactly you're using, but you might want to try `.val()` instead of `.text()`